# Python KeyError content

Tags: python-3.x

I'm new to python

I got this error in python3.6:

```
def getPosition(self,url):
    data = self.getData(url)
    position = data['content']['positionResult']['result']
    po_list = []
position = data['content']['positionResult']['result']
```

KeyError: 'content'

Comment: Look for Python `dict` documentation, *KeyError* means that the map does not contain the specified key. You can do `print('data = %s', data)` to output the data object.

Comment: The print command should be `print('data =', data)` or `print('data = %s' % data)`. Or simply `print(data)` if you do not need to be picky ;)